# Facebook PHP api, other users picture, how to obtain their ID?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-login

I need to make a php web page, that takes the current user FB profile picture.

So I followed these steps:
1. Created a Facebook app (obviously :-D )
2. Obtained the access token
3. Created the GET request

```
$fb = new \Facebook\Facebook([
   'app_id' => 'xxx',
   'app_secret' => 'xxx',
   'default_graph_version' => 'v3.3',
   'default_access_token' => 'xxx',
]);

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
$accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
$oAuth2Client = $fb->getOAuth2Client();

$response = $fb->get("me?fields=id,link,picture.width(9999)");
```

But "$response" always returns my profile, even if another user enter his own FB user/password.

Perhaps the problem is the url in the get "me", perhaps I need the user ID, but how???

Thanks in advance

Comment: No, `/me` automatically refers to the entity the access token belongs to (user or page.) If this is always returning the same profile, then it must be using the same user access token all the time - yours. So something went wrong with trying to login a different user then.

Comment: Thanks,
perhaps the 'default_access_token' (took from the developer console) forces to retrieve always my onw profile?

Comment: Yes, that’s probably it. (But you might still have to implement login properly to begin with, because the above doesn’t look like that - calling `$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();` by itself does not _trigger_ the process, you actually need to redirect the user to the resulting URL.)

Comment: Yeesss, I forgot an important detail: to add the token to the get request :-D
$response = $fb->get("me?fields=id,link,picture.width(9999)");
to
$response = $fb->get("me?fields=id,link,picture.width(9999)", $accessToken);